# How to select an instance of a model from a queryset django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am creating a project for hosting cricket tournaments. I have created 3 apps in it: home, tournament and team. After adding a tournament, when entering the tournament's detail view, I can add a team to the tournament. My `Team` model has a ForeignKey to my `Tournament` model, and my `Tournament` model has a ForeignKey to my `User` model(built-in django user model). When creating a team, I want to save the team for a particular tournament. I don't understand how to access the exact tournament and save the team for that tournament only.

My tournament detail html:

```
    {% extends 'menu.html' %}

    {% block content %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Match between</th>
            <th scope="col">Winner</th>
        </tr>
        {% for match in match_list %}
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{ match.team1.name }} vs {{ match.team2.name }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {% if match.winner %}
                        {{ match.winner.name }}
                    {% else %}
                        TBD
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
        {% if teamscount < tournament.no_of_teams %}
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'teams:addteam' %}'">Add Team</button>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>

    {% endblock content %}
```

My urls.py file in tournament app:

```
    from django.urls import path, include
    from . import views

    app_name='tournaments'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('all/', views.TournamentListView.as_view(), name='all'),
        path('create/', views.TournamentCreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
        path('view/<int:pk>/', views.TournamentDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    ]
```

My urls.py file in teams app:

```
    from django.urls import path
    from . import views

    app_name="teams"
    urlpatterns = [
        path('new/', views.TeamCreateView.as_view(), name="addteam"),
    ]
```

My views.py file in teams app:

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.views.generic import CreateView
    from .models import Team
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy
    from tournament.models import Tournament

    class TeamCreateView(CreateView):
        model = Team
        fields = ['name', 'no_of_players',]
        success_url = reverse_lazy('tournaments:all')
        success_message = "Tournament Created!!"

        def get_form(self):
            form = super().get_form()
            return form
 
       def form_valid(self, form):
            print('form_valid called')
            object = form.save(commit=False)
            object.tournament = Tournament.objects.filter(user = self.request.user)
            object.save()
            return super(TeamCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

My create team html file:

```
    {% extends 'menu.html' %}
    {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
    {% block content %}
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
    {% bootstrap_css %}
    {% bootstrap_javascript jquery='full' %}
    {{ form.media }}
    <form
        action="{% url 'teams:addteam' %}"
        method="post"
        id="upload_form"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
    >
         {% csrf_token %} {{ form|crispy }}
         <div class="form-group">
         <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Create</button>
         <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" onclick="window.location='{% url 'tournaments:all' %}' ; return false;" value="Cancel" />
         </div>
         </form>
    {% endblock content %}
```

How can I save this team to the specific tournament model, or do I need to change the way I've designed the functions and classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what i understood your models have the following design:

```
 class Tournament(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
            get_user_model(),
            on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

So, if you want to save a Team instance to a specific Tournament, you need to do the following:

```
# Grab the tournament instance in a variable (I recommend to use the id instead of the user. This is probably better, unless the user is unique per tournament, if not .get() will throw an error )
tournament = Tournament.objects.get(user=user)
# Then create your Team object like this
Team.objects.create(name='super team', tournament=tournament)
```

One of the problems i see is that you are using 'filter' alone to try to get an instance. 'Filter' returns a QuerySet. You have many choices to return a specific instance after using 'filter', you can do .filter().first() or .filter()[0] (or any number) and there are more

Comment: I've tried something like this, but the problem is there can be various tournaments(child model) that belong to a user(parent model). So how do I assign the particular tournament through which I entered the addteam page to be the parent of the team?

Comment: @Rohan, if you are accessing the 'addteam' page through a tournament, get the id of that tournament and use it in the .get(). Like this: Tournament.objects.get(id=1).  The id field is supposed to be unique, so you shouldn't have problems.

Maybe modify the path of the 'addteam'  url within the Team app and include an id variable (of the tournament) in the url path so you can grab it from there.

Comment: Yes, that did worked. I sent the pk of the tournament in the url to addteam, got it to get the exact tournament, and added the team to the tournament. In the form tag of my addteam html page, I removed the `action` attribute.